# Printing array of one view controller in another

Tags: nsarray

Can we print an array that is declared in one view controller class in another?

If so how can we do it?

I had tried on it several ways by importing the view controller,used NSLog... but couldn't do so,please do help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of approaching it can be declare the `delegate` of the `view controller` from which u want to pass the array. Now include the `delegate` in the other `view Controller` and call its `delegate` function. Pass the array u want to print in its `delegate` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of class1 to print in class2, do these.

1. Set array as a property of class1 and synthesize it.
2. Make sure you allocate it and add data to it.
3. Reference class1 in your class2 and create an object for class1.

   ```
   class1 *object1;
   ```
4. `object1.array` should now point to that array.

**Note:**

You will need to NSLog quite often and check if the array does not become null when you move to a different view controller and make sure you allocate it properly. Also, if possible allocate that array in your `AppDelegate` and then using the delegate property, `delegate.array` you will definitely be able to access it.